# subscribe is not defined in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a demo app in Angular 2 and want to console `params['id']` in my component, id is coming from query params.

To achieve this I am doing this in my component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.route.params
          .switchMap(
           (params: Params) => 
                this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
                console.log("ID :",params['id'])
           ).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    };
```

But i got this error:

```
core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: params is not defined
ReferenceError: params is not defined
```

Please suggest what I will have to do to console the param's id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `{}` to add more statements to an arrow function. I think you might want to do:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
         this.route.params
              .switchMap((params: Params) => {
  console.log("ID :",params['id']));
  return this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
  }) .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
};
```

> Why return?

The Observable that is returned by switchmap is subscribed in `subscribe` function. In case of arrow functions 
`()=>statment` is equivalent to `()=>{return statement;}`

When you add an additional statement and use brace you need to add the missing return.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: but why return in return this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']) ? @Suraj

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple statements, you need a block `{}`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => {
    var hero = this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
    console.log("ID :",params['id']);
    return hero;
  })
  .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

or

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => {
    console.log("ID :",params['id']);
    return this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']);
  })
  .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Günter Zöchbauer , Let me check.

Comment: I think you missed a return in switchmap call back

Comment: this is not working, i got this exception:- core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: Hard for me to know what you try to accomplish. What does `this.heroService.getHero()` return? I also added the suggestion from suraj.
A block needs an explicit `return` if you want to actually return something, and `switchMap` expects a return value.

Comment: what if the params is null? how to exit and avoid the '.subscribe method'?

Comment: I don't think `params` ever bwcomes `null`.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, this is my code http://i.prntscr.com/3lNpb5TZTCKTq8gaJTFQlA.png :(

Comment: Perhaps it's because you access `paramsMap` instead of `params`.

Comment: thanks for your attention. Well i get this routes http://i.prntscr.com/nlF1Xuh3QW_-EvVdz7rKcQ.png and when I access to 'clients/new' the component reads the id param as undefined... I know that i can change the route name but i would like to know if there is a way to cancel the subscription =)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what your problem is or what you try to accomplish.  `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` that you can use to `unsubscribe()`