# TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to `map` from a service call but getting an error.
Looked at [subscribe is not defined in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995647/subscribe-is-not-defined-in-angular-2) and it said that in order to subscribe we need to return from inside the operators. I have return statements as well.

Here's my code:

```ts
checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service
    .getData()
    .map(
      (response) => {
        this.data = response;
        this.checkservice = true;
        return true;
      },
      (error) => {
        // debugger;
        this.router.navigate(["newpage"]);
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }
    )
    .catch((e) => {
      return e;
    });
}
```

Error log:

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Comment: I received a similar issue: `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` but it happened while my server was running and I switched between branches. All I needed to do was restart my server and it went away.

Comment: @AakashThakur Your return type is `Observable<boolean>`. So, all of your return statements should return an Observable of boolean. Wrap return statement with `of()`. Example 1: `return of(false)` Example 2: `return of(e)`

Answer (score 52):

In my case the error occurred only during e2e tests. It was caused by `throwError` in my AuthenticationInterceptor.

I imported it from a wrong source because I used WebStorm's import feature. I am using RxJS 6.2.

Wrong:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/throwError';
```

Correct:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

Here the full code of the interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const reqWithCredentials = req.clone({withCredentials: true});
    return next.handle(reqWithCredentials)
     .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
            // handle error
          }
          return throwError(error);
        })
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might have two versions in your project at the same time if you are in the middle of transitioning to RxJS 6 using the rxjs-compat library.

Comment: I had a similar case, my interceptor was only doing the `next.handle(request)` call in a if. So intercepting a request and not calling handle afteward will result in this message.

Comment: I had a similar issue bringing in `interval` from the wrong place in `rxjs`.  This was an extremely helpful answer, thanks!

Comment: In my case I only had  `retrun` and  not`return throwError(error)` .thanks for the answer.

Comment: I cannot stress how much this answer was important! fixed an issue I am following for two days... Thanks!

Comment: I was definitely sending null headers in and INTERCEPTOR. That it was in the interceptor is what really helped here.

Answer (score 21):

In your example code, you have your `map` operator receiving two callbacks, when it should only be receiving one. You can move your error handling code to your catch callback.

```
checkLogin():Observable<boolean>{
    return this.service.getData()
                       .map(response => {  
                          this.data = response;                            
                          this.checkservice=true;
                          return true;
                       })
                       .catch(error => {
                          this.router.navigate(['newpage']);
                          console.log(error);
                          return Observable.throw(error);
                       })
   }
```

You'll need to also import the `catch` and `throw` operators.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

**EDIT:** 
Note that by returning `Observable.throw`in your catch handler, you won't actually capture the error - it will still surface to the console.

Comment: But I get this error now:`Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object ProgressEvent]`

Comment: you can try changing the `Observable.throw` line to `Observable.of`  (and include the import). That will cause your observable to emit the error, but it won't treat it like a failure. (basically we're kinda/but-not-quite swallowing the error). See if that removes the error from the console. If it does, then it points to the getData() method failing

Answer (score 19):

If your function is expecting to return a boolean, just do this:

1. Import:

```js
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

2. Then

```js
checkLogin(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service.getData()
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        this.data = response;
        this.checkservice = true;
        return true;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        this.router.navigate(['newpage']);
        console.log(error);
        return of(false);
      })
)}
```

Answer (score 10):

You are returning an Observable where as your code returns just a boolean. So you need to use as below

```
.map(response => <boolean>response.json())
```

If you are using another common service `checkservice` in your case, you can simply use

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

This will make your `checkLogin()` function with return type as void

```
 checkLogin():void{
      this.service.getData()
            .map(response => {  
                           this.data = response;                            
                           this.checkservice=true;
             }).subscribe(data=>{ });
```

and you can use of `this.checkService` to check your condition

Comment: I have to return an `Observable<boolean>` because I have to make use of it in some other function.

Comment: what is your getData() function returns?

Comment: getData() returns `[object Object]{id: "1234", isAdmin: false, userName: "Lama", newid: Array[1]}`

Comment: Sorry brother. I am not.

Comment: I wont be able to reproduce or show you my screen because its not a home project, its something that is confidential and this is just a part where I had problem.

Comment: ok. fine. can you update the flow of your code to post ? full flow ?

Answer (score 7):

I've had this error when there's been different RxJS-versions across projects. The internal checks in RxJS fails because there are several different `Symbol_observable`. Eventually [this function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3db2eaa5d6bfe0188b0c4da3626123c8eefedf98/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts#L15) throws once called from a flattening operator like `switchMap`.

Try importing symbol-observable in some entry point.

```
// main index.ts
import 'symbol-observable';
```

Answer (score 6):

I was forgetting to return the other observable in `pipe(switchMap(`

```
this.dataService.getPerson(personId).pipe(
  switchMap(person => {
     //this.dataService.getCompany(person.companyId); // return missing
     return this.dataService.getCompany(person.companyId);
  })
)
```

Comment: I didn't properly mock the observable returned in a `switchMap` in my unit tests with the same result.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue caused by importing the internal version of 'takeUntil' instead of the operators
Change

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/takeUntil';
```

to

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**This happen also for other operators**

Answer (score 4):

### Can be triggered by a stray comma (`,`) in an RxJS `pipe(...)`

The compile won't catch this extra comma at the end:

```
pipe(first(), map(result => ({ event: 'completed', result: result}),);
```

It becomes an 'invisible' `undefined` operator which screws the whole pipe up, and leads to a very confusing error message - which in this case has nothing to do with my actual logic.

Answer (score 3):

A hint for anyone experiencing this. This can happen when a `switchMap` doesn't receive an observable return value (like **null**). Simply add a default case, so it always returns an observable.

```
        switchMap((dateRange) => {
          if (dateRange === 'Last 24 hours') {
            return $observable1;
          }
          if (dateRange === 'Last 7 Days') {
            return $observable2;
          }
          if (dateRange === 'Last 30 Days') {
            return $observable3;
          }
          // This line will work for default cases
          return $observableElse;
        })
```

Comment: This was my case, I was testing a function, but I didn't need the return value of an observable that was returned from switchMap, so I didn't mock it, I had to :D It helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing this issue when trying to authenticate a user using JSON Web Token. in my case it's related to authentication interceptor.

Sending a request to authenticate a user doesn't have to provide a token since it doesn't exist yet.

Check that your interceptor include this:

```
if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
            return next.handle(req.clone());
```

And that you provide `{'No-Auth':'True'}` to your header's request like this:

```
  authenticateUser(user): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'True'});
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiEndpoint}/auth/authenticate`, user, {headers: headers});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this because I arrive here searching for the same error, and this could be useful for someone in the future.

I get the same error while trying to initialize a service variable from its constructor making a call to a remote API trough http.get and *.subscribe()*

After many tests without understanding what the problem was, i finally get it:
My application had authentication and an *HttpInterceptor*, and i was trying to initialize the service calling a public API method using *http.get(...)* without *'No-Auth'* headers. I added them like here, and problem solved for me:

```
getData() {
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });    
return this.http.get(environment.urlApi.Literales, { headers: reqHeader });  
}
```

What a headache :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact error message while I was doing my unit test and throwing observable exception after mocking my services.

I resolved it by passing exact function and format inside `Observable.throw`.

Actual code which calls the service and `subscribe` to get data. notice that `catch` to handle the `400` error.

```
     this.search(event).catch((e: Response) => {
        if (e.status === 400) {
          console.log(e.json().message);
        } else if (e.url) {
          console.log('HTTP Error: ' + e.status + ' ' + e.statusText,
            'URL: ' + e.url, 'Info: ' + e.json().message));
        }
      }).finally(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      }).subscribe((bData) => {
        this.data = bData;
      });
```

The code inside the service

```
  search() {
    return this.someService.getData(request)
       .do((r) => {
          this.someService.defaultHeaders.delete('skipAlert');
          return r;
        })
      .map((r) => {
          return r.businessObjectDataElements.length && r.businessObjectDataElements || null;
        });
  }
```

#### Unit Testing

I have mocked the SomeService and returning observable data and its fine as it have all the required methods inside it.

```
 someServiceApi = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);
 spyOn(someServiceApi, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of({}));
```

The above code is okey but when when I was trying to test the catch/error condition by passing `Observable.throw({})` it was showing me the error as it was expecting `Response` type return from the service.

So below service mocking return was giving me that error.

```
someServiceApi.getData
  .and.returnValue(Observable.throw(new Response({status: 400, body: [], message: 'not found error'})));
```

So I Corrected it by replicating the exact expected function in my return object rather passing a `Response` type value.

```
someServiceApi.getData
  .and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 400, json: () => { return {message: 'not found error'}}, body: []}));
// see `json: () => { return {message: 'not found error'}}` inside return value
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Angular-5, service file was not imported from which i was accessing the method and subscribing the data.After importing service file it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

this error happened with me when i am using interceptor 
you have to do this in your interceptor

```
return next.handle(request).map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

        }
        return event;
    },
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 400) {
          // some logic

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me @angular 7

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

The error is actually self-explanatory, it says `somewhere` in the observable I pass the invalid object. In my case, there was lots of API call but all the calls were failing because of wrong server configuration. I tried to use `map`, `switchMap`, or other rxjs operator but the operators are getting undefined objects.

So double-check your rxjs operator inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when i was calling a method inside switchMap, apparently I found that if we use method inside switchMap it must return observable.

i used pipe to return observable and map to perform operations inside pipe for an api call which i was doing inside method rather than subscribing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone, but in my case further up my chain I was using `distinctUntilChanged` and an exception inside a function there was manifesting with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the following error message too when you provide undefined or so to an operator which *expects an Observable*, eg. **takeUntil**.

```
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I mistakely imported Action into my combineEpics, rather than Epic...

Verify all the functions within combine Epics are epic funcitons

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using RXJS in NESTJS.

```
Error: TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. +1ms
```

In my case I forgot to return an Observable in a switchMap. This caused that no Observable was received in the next RXJS operator or client code.

Once I returned an Observable in the switchMap, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Error with a different Problem, so im answering my solution here so when people are searching for the same thing might see this.

I followed the Supabase + Ionic Auth Tutorial and wanted to add Email-Validation (with Angular Reactive Forms). I defined my Validation-Group like this:

```
  credentials = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
                  email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
                  password: ['', Validators.required],
  })
```

And when i added the Validators.email i suddenly got the error, i never really looked at the Validators-lib, but when i did i saw that you need to pass the second Validations as an Array. So simply changing `['', Validators.required, Validators.email]` to `['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]` fixed the problem!

Working Solution:

```
  credentials = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
                  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
                  password: ['', Validators.required],
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

In regard to the **"You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable"** error.

This could happen if you `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` **after** (below) some module/function/whatever, which actually uses it.

**Solution**: move this import **above** the import of that module.