# How to handle the error in angular with catch error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using angular 7. This is my service.

```
get(){
return this.http.post(this.url).pipe(
catchError(this.handleError)
)
}
```

This is the error handler code.

```
handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      return throwError(errorResponse.error.message)
    } else {
      switch (errorResponse.status) {
        case 400:
          return throwError(errorResponse.error.message)
        case 401:
          return throwError(errorResponse.error.message)
        case 409:
          return throwError(errorResponse.error.message)
        case 500:
          return throwError(errorResponse.error.message)
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the error I am receiving when the submit button is pressed.

```
core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:43)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:79)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:13)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:18)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
```

please help me in this situation.

Comment: You probably don't return anything from in `catchError`'s callback.

Comment: use try catch. Put your code in try and in catch console the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549223/typeerror-you-provided-an-invalid-object-where-a-stream-was-expected-you-can-p)

Comment: whats is the response of the HTTP request that causes the issue? you might need to add a default case to your switch

Answer (score 1):

You are returning undefined from your catchError operator. The catchError operator expects you to return an observable.

```
get(){
    return this.http.post(this.url).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
            // handle the error

            // use the empty() factory method to return an observable
            // that emits nothing and completes
            return empty();
        })
    )
}
```

Reference: [empty](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/empty.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an error stating that you have failed to provide a stream in your observable.

This usually happens when you don't provide an observable to operators such as `switchMap`, `combineLatest`, or in this case, `catchError`.

Simply add a

```
return of(undefined);
```

in your `catchError` to resolve the issue.