# How to subscribe on result of flatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

How to subscribe on result of flatMap?

```
   timer(0, 2000)
      .pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.scannerService.scan(this.scanType)),
        takeWhile(res => res.errorDesc !== "SUCCESS")
      )
      .subscribe((res: IScanResponse) => {
});
```

I tried do use `.subscribe()` after `pipe`. But I get error as:

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can
>   provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

My remote function is:

```
public scan(scanType: string): Observable<any> {}
```

My imports are:

```
import { timer } from "rxjs";
import { takeWhile } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ScannerService } from "src/app/api/ScannerService";
import { flatMap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: Have you tried `.subscribe()` directly after takeWhile or after the pipe ?

Comment: Directly after `pipe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your type returned by `scan`

In a `flatMap`, you need to **return an Observable**.

And here you return `Observable<any> {}` instead of just `Observable<any>`

Comment: Just add return key?

Comment: It depends what you is the object. But yes, you can do something like : `.scan(..)[theKey]`

Comment: I really dont understand you, my scan function is:

Comment: ``` public scan(scanType: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(environment.scanService, { scanType: scanType });
  } ```

Comment: If your scan function works like this, then it's good. No need for .scan(...)[key]. I though that your function return an object with an observable inside but no.

Answer (score 1):

After the `.pipe()` since `.pipe()` returns an observable

```
const tm = timer(0, 2000).pipe(
     flatMap(() => this.scannerService.scan(this.scanType)),
     takeWhile(res => res)
).subscribe(res=> {
//your code
});;
```

Comment: It seems that he has already tried subscribe after the pipe. So his error is probably  somewhere else. (Maybe a wrong import from another library than rxjs)

Comment: My import see in question please

Comment: @OPV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549223/typeerror-you-provided-an-invalid-object-where-a-stream-was-expected-you-can-p/43549301 maybe this helps