# Catch Error is not being called when i throw an error in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor

I have added an HTTP interceptor to catch all possible errors from the request and then throw that error using throwError

```
    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        const currentuser = this.accountService.isLoggedIn;
        const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        if (currentuser && token !== undefined) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders:
                {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`

                }
            });
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });

            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                debugger
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

                    const unothorizedError = error;

                    if (unothorizedError.status === 401) {
                        if (unothorizedError.error != null) {
                            return throwError(unothorizedError.error);
                        }
                    }

                    if (unothorizedError.status === 0) {
                        return throwError('Connection failed to the server');
                      }

                    const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');

                    if (applicationError) {
                        return throwError(applicationError);
                    }

                    const serverError = error.error;
                    let modalStateErrors = '';

                    if (serverError && serverError.errors && typeof serverError.errors === 'object') {
                        for (const key in serverError.errors) {
                            if (serverError.errors[key]) {
                                modalStateErrors += serverError.errors[key] + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

And I am trying to catch the error from my resolver but when I was debugging I notice that catch error is not being called

```
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Product[]> {
    debugger
    return this.productsService
      .getAllProducts(this.pageNumber, this.pageSize, null)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.log(error);
          // this.snackBar.open('Problem retriving your data', 'cancel', {
          //   duration: 5000 ,
          // });
          // this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          return of(null);
        })
      );}
```

And then `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` is being thrown.

So its like I can't catch the error given from my interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this question in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860785/you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expected) and i added

```
else {return throwError(error);}
```

in the HTTP Interceptor and it works but i don't know why